# How to describe table that I only have part of name?

Tags: mysql

I have an old script that creates each day a table and store data in it.

The table names are like this `today-date-some-other-string`, i.e : `02-02-2018-other-string`.

The question is, how could I describe the structure of that table despite I only have today's date? I mean is there a way to do something like this :

```
DESC WHERE Table like "02-02-2018%"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not select from information_schema.columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you could use prepared statements for example

```
set @sql = concat('describe ' , (select table_name 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_name like 'users' and table_schema = 'sandbox')
,';');


prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```